# c++ convert vector<pair<double,double>> to double*, double*?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

Is there a way to get the contiguous memory of the ".first" and ".second" of `vector<pair<double,double>>`? What I mean is:

```
void func(int N, double* x, double* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        //do something to x[i] and y[i]
}
```

For the above function I have a `vector<pair<double,double>> point` rather than `vector<double> x, y`. I'm guessing this is not possible. If I had a vector x,y then I could do x.data() and y.data() of course.

Comment: Cant you change the function to work on the vector as it is? If not you have to iterate through the array and fill a new vector. Alternatively you could write your own iterators for the `vector<pair<double,double>>` that iterate on the first/second respectively.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `&vec[0]` to get a pointer to element 0. But if there is a pair inside of the vector one still has to do `vec[0].first` or `vec[0].second`.

Comment: btw the pairs are in contiguous memory, but the x (and the y) are not

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a problem of concept. Maybe it's impossible to have contiguous memory of all the x values and all the y values in `vector<pair<double,double>>` while also maintaining that there is contiguous memory of `vector<double>`. They must be physically/conceptually opposing ideas. We'd need a custom container or iterator or something.

Comment: Please answer the question: Can you change the function? And also, why do you have the `vector<pair<double,double>>` can you change this?

Comment: Yes I can change the function, but that's not exactly the point of this question. I've run into situations like this a handful of times and I want to know if there's a way to avoid creating new containers/copying/etc or changing the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory layouts of `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> xy` and `std::vector<double> x,y` are different. If `func` is part of a third-party library you can not change, you are bound to

a) call `func` a couple of times with `N=1` or (quick an dirty)

```
auto xy = std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> {
  {0,0}, {42,0}, {0, 42}, {42, 42}
};
for (auto& [x,y] : xy) { // or for (auto& p : xy) func(1, p.first, p.second)
  func(1, &x, &y);
}
```

b) convert `xy` to `x` and `y`

```
template <typename T, typename S>
auto convert(const std::vector<std::pair<T,S>>& xy)
{
  auto xs = std::vector<T>{};
  auto ys = std::vector<S>{};
  xs.reserve(xy.size());
  ys.reserve(xy.size());
  for (auto& [x,y] : xy) {
    xs.push_back(x);
    ys.push_back(y);
  }
  return std::make_pair(xs, ys);
}

int main()
{
  auto xy = std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> {
    {0,0}, {42,0}, {0, 42}, {42, 42}
  };
  auto [x, y] = convert(xy);
  func(xy.size(), x.data(), y.data());
}
```

c) simply change the defintions of `xy` to `x` and `y`.

If you can change `func`, I propose to refactor such that you can call the inner loop and rewrite it for iterators (or ranges). That way you could use it with projections on `std::pair`s.

[Here is the full source code.](https://godbolt.org/g/kgCTG2)

Comment: aha, interesting to note that A won't work because this particular function requires summing of multiple indexes to change value of y (a la convolution). So it looks like the only option is using `separate x and y` rather than `pair of x and y` or changing the function.

Comment: I added the source code for converting the vector into the seperate ones. Care must be taken if the vector is big. Im not sure about the extra allocations and copies through the `std::make_pair` call.